# Is styling html tags bad practice?

Tags: html, css

Is it bad practice, for example, to put

```
img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

to make all of the images on my webpage responsive instead of using

```
img-responsive
```

to everything, or styling my h1 to h6 tags.

Comment: if it's just like for css reset , it's fine . like `*{margin:0;padding:0;}` , but it's for everything , no , you should not do that .

Comment: I would say even when you want to apply the styling to a tag entirely, it's better to use a parent class with it: `.may-image-container img {...}`

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not bad practice. Learning to differentiate the concept is the key here.

Usually tags styling are used only to define/reset styles at the most generic base for your webpage. The most common case you can see is used for reseting the styling for cross-browser purpose. There are a few supporting this like [Normalize.CSS](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)  will do this.

Then, when your project depends on a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation, they will have their own styling. Usually at this stage they use classes for a better structure and re-use.

From here, you can either choose to inherit the style from the framework, or make your own.

On a side note, it still recommends to use classes for styling. Given this HTML structure for example.

```
<div class="profile">
  <img class="avatar-url" src="..." />
  <p>John</p>
</div>
```

and

```
.profile p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

It works for the time being, when `name` is the only thing it has. As time changes, you might need to add `title` to the `profile` block.

```
<div class="profile">
  <img class="avatar-url" src="..." />
  <span class="title">Mr. </span><span class="name">John</span>
</div>
```

Now, you might see a few issues here, including:

- Your CSS will break because there's no more `<p>` tag around.
- Need to rewrite CSS to apply to new structure. In term of scalability, this is considered bad practice because it might breaks somewhere else you might have no control.
- You were forcing the name to use `<p>` tag. When one tag has its own defined properties that need to be changed to another, consider that might break your layout. Especially switching between `inline` and `block` display attribute.

Plus, using styles with class also increases the readability of your code. It's always easier to read something like `.list .item` than a `.list div`.

In term of CSS specificity calculation, tag is the lowest priority. So, to override a defined class like `.btn`, you need to use `.btn` at least.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad practice at all. But classes are useful if you need different styles for your images in your whole website. Maybe you need some images with a fixed width, and other images with display: block and some box-shadow, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to style base html elements. A common practice is to use a css reset file or a set of rules designed to reset all the default styles. This is because browser defaults may not all be identical. Here is a good workflow:

1. reset all browser defaults. You can find many good css reset rule sets online. I would recommend the [html5 doctor resets](https://cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/) as a good option for a modern css reset.
2. Set your own default styles for html elements on your site. These are the default styles that apply to all `<img>`, `<h1>` through `<h6>`, `<a>` etc.. This is useful because it makes your html cleaner without requiring tons of classes on every single element.
3. Where you have specific elements which must deviate from the site's default styles, or sections which require complex design patterns which can not be accomplished with the site's defaults styles. use classes and IDs as needed.

There are of course other methodologies, which are equally valid. You might look into some of the popular CSS methodologies like [OOCS](http://oocss.org/), [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/), or [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/), which are merely formalized sets of conventions which aim at making your CSS more manageable and reusable.